# Show and hide divs with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello again with this code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/9/ , so I have a problem, when I select one of 5 links from the first column i get second div to show up with 3 links, again when I click on them I get a third div with links to text in fourth div. The problem here is after I select one of the links from the first div, I get the second one, and after I select one from second I get a thrid div(column) which shows the same data in all divs. Basicly this first link called felge(wheels) works fine, but the problem is that I need diferent text in the third div if I select something else than felge

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="div" id="subcontent1">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci1')" id="treci1">RS-6</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci2')" id="treci2">RB</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci3')" id="treci3">KR-A</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="div" id="subcontent2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci4')" id="treci4">ENKEI92</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci5')" id="treci5">EDR9</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci6')" id="treci6">YS5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="div" id="subcontent3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci7')" id="treci7">INTERFORM</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci8')" id="treci8">TWEAKD SILVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci9')" id="treci9">HELIX BLACK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="div" id="subcontent4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci10')" id="treci10">INFORM</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci11')" id="treci11">TWD SILVER</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:showtreci('treci12')" id="treci12">HELACK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with fourth subcontent to add diferent text if I press on gume, but that doesnt work. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: clicking on any link in your fiddle doesnt do anything at all...

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is not working that way you described it.

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work Spacemonkey, I just opened it and links work.

Comment: Tom, what do you men its not working the way I described it?

Comment: Try it:
https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/8/
You probably use another revision...

Comment: It works for me. I added updated version on top in my link, rewision 9, does that work?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but do you want to update **contentx**, **subcontentx** & **contentTrix** divs based on `change` of selection in **menu** div so that when `Felge` is selected from `menu`, `content1` should not only become visible but `BBS` (which is the first option in `content1`) also gets selected which also makes `RS-6` (which is the first option in `subcontent1`) becomes selected & hence text in `contentTri1` is displayed? You want the changes to trickle down based on whichever level you click on?

Comment: Yes, Tahir, that is correct. I got it working now, had to change few things in code but it works now

Comment: @slamek10, can you then share your code with the rest of us as an *answer* then please. So we can learn too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding the question exactly but I think it could be easily solved with JQUERY.  If you can use JQUERY, hiding and showing divs are very easy.  Here is a JS Fiddle Example for you to look at.

**https://jsfiddle.net/7jmdsaj3/**

JQUERY

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    var ok = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.'+ok+'.content').fadeIn();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="one" class="btn">one</div>
<div id="two" class="btn">two</div>
<div id="three" class="btn">three</div>
<div id="four" class="btn">four</div>

<div class="one content">here is the content for one</div>
<div class="two content">two two two</div>
<div class="three content">third area of content is here</div>
<div class="four content">44 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
    display:none;
}
```